# How to get a variable's value from a registerReceiver inner class

Tags: java, android, variables, outer-classes

Hi I am writing an application for Android. I use Android Studio 2.1 and Android 4.0.3. My application uses Wi-Fi data and I can not get a variable's content from outer class. I am using registerReceiver and I try to get a variable in that register receiver inner class. I'm sorry for my poor English. When I debug, I see that activityString is null. Please help. My code is here:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
public String activityString; // Here static or not no difference. This is null

public static WifiManager wifi;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.locationscreen);

    wifiScanResults();

    String[] dataArray = activityString.split("\\.");

    // Here I got Null Referance exception. When I debug, activityString is null
}

public void wifiScanResults()
{ 
     wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
     registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

        activityString = "Go";

        }
      }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

    wifi.startScan();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a private inner class. I think you can not fetch anything from it. Instead, you should do whatever you will do inside it. For example you can write your code in it.